# Object detection Classfication /A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights)

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I am try to classfication with object detection at the colab.I am using "ssd_resnet101_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.config"When I start to training I get error.
Training=

```
!python model_main_tf2.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_resnet101_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.config \
    --model_dir=training \
    --alsologtostderr
```

```
WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
W1130 13:39:27.991891 140559633127296 util.py:158] A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
```

Answer (score 9):

I was dealing with the same error.  I assume that the training stopped when you got the error you cited above.  If so, you might want to check your folder paths.

I was able to get rid of the error myself when I figured out that I was trying to create a new model but TF was looking to a 'model_dir' folder that contained checkpoints from my previous model.  Because my num_steps was not greater than the num_steps used in the previous model, TF effectively stopped running the training because the num_steps had already been completed.

By changing the model_dir to a brand new folder, I was able to overcome this error and begin training a new model.  Hopefully this works for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is trying **to continue** their training, the solution as @GbG mentioned is to update your `num_steps` value in the `pipeline.config`:

Original:

```
  num_steps: 25000
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: .04
          total_steps: 25000
```

Updated:

```
  num_steps: 50000
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: .04
          total_steps: 50000
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you trained your model enough num_steps in your config file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).